# 3.3V @ 10mA from 5V - 35V

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

Any ideas on how to get 3.3V from 5V - 35V at a low 10mA current level? 3.3V need not be precise. It can be 3.5V or 3V, it is powering a small microcontroller.

I'm looking for a small and cost effective solution. That pretty much rules out through hole stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a linear regulator that can handle 5V to 35V input. It outputs 3.3V.

It is that simple. You can use a buck regulator, if efficiency is an issue. but 10mA at a 35V drop is still only a 350mW dissipation.

I suggest the linear, keep components/complexity/noise down.

Comment: efficiency gain from a buck regulator at only 10mA would be questionable as well, especially at the 35V point, the duty cycle would be really low.

Comment: 350mW is a lot for small surface mount components.

Comment: 350mW absolutely worse case is not that bad. that is if you are at 38V in. If you get a good ground plane to conduct heat, or use through hole with a heat sink(which I can put watts into without a problem) you can handle this. The question of heat dissipation we have had other places. This will easily be handled with small surface-mount linear regulator(I have done this much power that way).

Comment: Yeah, but I can't spare space for through hole. It's also a waste of space in that the micro is in a tiny SO20 package but the reg is in a TO-220... How would zener diodes work? they have higher dissipation ratings, maybe it would work better?

Comment: It's also not a worst case scenario, a lot of people will be using 30V battery packs with this.

Comment: something like a http://www.linear.com/pc/productDetail.jsp?navId=H0,C1,C1040,P86928 in a DFN package with the thermal pad tied to the ground plane with 3-4 vias would work fine.  Based on the data sheet you would need something like 25cm^2 of copper to allow operation up to ~90C ambient.  Which if you have a ground plane in the board and the board is bigger than 5cm x 5cm should be fine.  If you can do a ground pour on the surface layer around the IC, even better.

Comment: @thomas, telling me that the 35V could be continuous is something I did not account for. I would have given the same answer though. I have used in excess of 30V with a small surface mount package and more than 10mA. I give a nice big ground plane.

Comment: Do not use a zener. They will not give you regulated voltage like you get with a wonderful linear regulator and they will kill power.

Answer (score 3):

You'd struggle to find a buck reg with 35v input range that didn't draw 10mA quiescent before you got any power out. 
35V is a bit on the high side for many linear regs so you need to look carefully at specs.

Comment: tcrosley disproved you without much effort `:P`.  LTC3631 has a maximum `Iq` of 0.22 mA in active state.  `Iq` is usually proportional to the full-load capability, so while you're probably right for a 5A supply, smaller ones exist.

Comment: The OP said "Cost effective" - LTC3631 costs maybe  3-4x what the "small micro" is likely to.

Comment: Micro is a PIC16F690, about $1.80 in quantity.

Answer (score 3):

This [LTC3631](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3631) handles 4.5 to 45V in, 3.3v out, and comes in either a 3x3 mm or MSOP-8 package.  81% efficiency at 36v in and 10 ma out (page 4).  You should be able to get a suitable inductor in an 0805 (2 x 1.3 mm) or smaller package.

The [MC34063](http://www.st.com/stonline/products/literature/ds/5257/mc34063ab.pdf) might also work but it is a larger package (SOIC-8), uses more quiescent current (2.5 ma) and would require more external components.  But it is 1/4 the cost of the LTC3631.

Answer (score 2):

At such a low current level I would be inclined to pre-regulate down with say a 12v zener and stick a cheap-as-chips LDO on there

Comment: At such a low current it wouldn't be entirely out of the question to use a voltage divider instead of an LDO if they wanted to be really cheap, but yes, I think an LDO or standard 3.3 volt regulator would be better in terms of voltage stability.